# How to get dummies and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have dataframe below

```
   Q  A
A  a  h  
A  b  i
A  c  j
B  d  k
B  a  l 
B  b  m
C  c  n
```

I would like to get dummy and groupby

```
    a   b   c   d    e   f   g
A   h   i   j  nan  nan nan nan
B   l  nan nan nan  k   nan nan      
C  nan nan  n  nan  nan nan nan
```

`col=df.Q`

I must apply `get_dummies`and`groupby`.but I couldnt figure out.

How can I get this result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().pivot(index='index', columns='Q', values='A')
print (df)
Q         a     b     c     d
index                        
A         h     i     j  None
B         l     m  None     k
C      None  None     n  None
```

And then if neccessary [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
cols = list('abcdefg')
print (df.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1).replace({None:np.nan}))
Q        a    b    c    d   e   f   g
index                                
A        h    i    j  NaN NaN NaN NaN
B        l    m  NaN    k NaN NaN NaN
C      NaN  NaN    n  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

EDIT:

If duplicates in data better is `groupby` with `join`:

```
print (df)
   Q  A
A  a  h
A  b  i
A  c  j
B  d  k
B  a  l
B  b  m <-duplicates B b
B  b  t <-duplicates B b
C  c  n


df = df.reset_index().groupby(['index','Q'])['A'].apply(','.join).unstack()
print (df)
Q         a     b     c     d
index                        
A         h     i     j  None
B         l   m,t  None     k
C      None  None     n  None
```

Another possible solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
#aggfunc='first' - get only first value, another values are lost
df1 = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='index', columns='Q', values='A', aggfunc='first')
print (df1)
Q         a     b     c     d
index                        
A         h     i     j  None
B         l     m  None     k
C      None  None     n  None
Q         a     b     c     d

#aggfunc='sum' - summed data, no separator
df2 = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='index', columns='Q', values='A', aggfunc='sum')
print (df2)
index                        
A         h     i     j  None
B         l    mt  None     k
C      None  None     n  None
Q         a     b     c     d

#aggfunc=','.join - summed data with separator
df3 = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='index', columns='Q', values='A', aggfunc=','.join)
print (df3)
index                        
A         h     i     j  None
B         l   m,t  None     k
C      None  None     n  None
```